# Does iOS support the "beforeinstallpromp" event?

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps, dom-events, workbox

Chrome in Android and Desktop supports "beforeinstallpromp" event which is can show up add to homescreen banner. I'm try to use the same javascript code for my PWA in iOS but it is doesn't work.

```js
/**
 * Clear caches
 */
function pwaClearCaches()
{
    //Clear caches
    caches.keys().then(function(names) {
        for (let name of names) {
            caches.delete(name);
        }
    });
}

var pwa_app_installed = false; //PWA is already installed
var deferredPrompt; //Link to show dialog event
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') { //Если это HTTP протокол, а не HTTPS
        console.log(lang.t('You need HTTPS for work'));
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        /**
         * Подвешиваемся на переключение режима правки, чтобы сразу очистить кэш
         */
        $('.debug-mode-switcher').on('click', function () {
            if (!$('.debug-mode-switcher .toggle-switch').hasClass('on')) {
                //Delete service worker
                navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
                    for (let registration of registrations) {
                        registration.unregister();
                    }
                });

                //Clear caches
                pwaClearCaches();
            }
        });
    }

    if ($.cookie('update_pwa_cache')){ //Update cache if we have cookie на обновление
        pwaClearCaches();
        $.cookie('update_pwa_cache', '', {expires: -1});
    }

    /**
     * Close window with prompt
     */
    function closePWAInstallWindow()
    {
        $("#pwaInstall").hide();
        $.cookie('not_show_pwa', '1');
    }

    let body = $('body');
    /**
     * Add to homescreen event 
     */
    body.on('click', '#pwaAddToHomeScreen', function(){
        deferredPrompt.prompt(); // Show alert to install
        deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {//Wait for user choose
            if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') { //Accept install
                closePWAInstallWindow();
            } else { //Cansel install
                closePWAInstallWindow();
            }
            deferredPrompt = null;
        });
        return false;
    });
    /**
     * Close intalll window
     */
    body.on('click', '#pwaCloseInstall', function(){
        closePWAInstallWindow();
        return false;
    });
});


console.log('out');

//If we not in webapp and no session that we need to install
if (!(window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) && !$.cookie('not_show_pwa')) {
    /**
     * Event that app is installed
     */
    $(window).on('appinstalled', (evt) => {
        pwa_app_installed = true;
    });

    console.log('not fired');

    /**
     * Event beforeinstallprompt from browser
     */
    $(window).on('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
        e.preventDefault();
        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        deferredPrompt = e.originalEvent;
        console.log('fired');

        var is_mobile_android = false;
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;

        if (/Android/i.test(ua) && /Chrome/i.test(ua)){ //If we in Android and it is Chrome prevent native window
            is_mobile_android = true;
        }

        if (!pwa_app_installed && !is_mobile_android){
            let body = $('body');
            body.append('<div id="pwaInstall" class="pwaInstall" style="background-color: #fff">' +
                '<div class="content">Please install our app</div><div class="links">' +
                    '<a href="#" id="pwaAddToHomeScreen" style="background-color: #fff; color: #000;">Add to homescreen</a>' +
                    '<a href="#" id="pwaCloseInstall" style="background-color: yellow; color: black;">No Thanks</a>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>');

            setTimeout(function () { //Show our banner
                $("#pwaInstall").addClass('show');
            }, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And I have manifest.json

```
{
    "short_name": "VaporStore",
    "name": "VaporStore & FreeVape",
    "description": "Магазин свободного пара",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/storage/system/resized/xy_64x64/0f08cd435767735a778ea63fea5b5efd_e2f1b76.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "64x64"
        },
        {
            "src": "/storage/system/resized/xy_128x128/0f08cd435767735a778ea63fea5b5efd_b510eb77.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "128x128"
        },
        {
            "src": "/storage/system/original/0f08cd435767735a778ea63fea5b5efd.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "192x192"
        },
        {
            "src": "/storage/system/original/272d68dfbb5e80ef67f6c7abcb2391cb.png",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "512x512"
        }
    ],
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "theme_color": "#ff9800",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": "/"
}
```

And I have service worker based on workbox from Google.

Does iOS support the "beforeinstallpromp" event or not? On Android and Desktop chrome works fine.

**Update 04.04.2019**
The most full answer is given here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5ASNwnBttQ

from the clip: "iOS 12.2 does not support beforeinstallprompt" (mention is made of add to home screen behavior via 'Share Screen')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Comment: perhaps on Chrome iOS https://love2dev.com/blog/beforeinstallprompt/

Comment: I have made all the same. But it is not working my domain is vaporstore.kz . Service worker https://vaporstore.kz/serviceworker.js

Comment: Are you sure you are totally uninstalling and clearing out the browser's cache for each test? Perhaps have someone new with the latest version of Chrome iOS test for you.

Comment: I'm testing not in Chrome for iOS. I want to make it work on standard browser for ios - Safari.

Comment: @AlexanderZakusilo BeforeInstallPromptEvent is not supported in Safari iOS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

beforeinstallprompt is not available in iOS Safari
See list at the bottom of this page
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

Comment: I think that it is old information. This page have date in the bottom.  Last updated by: chrisdavidmills, Dec 11, 2018

Comment: I have not seen anywhere that it works with Safari. A Google search might help you find someone who has built some work around.

Comment: IOS doesn't support 'beforeinstallprompt' yet! So I think to show a custom a2hs message to users, we can simply first check these 2 conditions: 1. Our user is on an IOS platform. 2. She's not already viewing your site from a standalone mode. If the conditions are true, then we show our custom IOS message. Otherwise, we go further and now add the 'beforeinstallprompt' event and etc... Here is a nice tutorial on how to check the IOS related conditions (check out #PROTIP 3 section): https://www.netguru.com/codestories/pwa-ios